# how can I group table tr useing jquery faster and better way

Tags: jquery

I want to group table tr by rowspan attribute like below
how can I do faster useing jquery?
do any can help?

```
<table border=1 width='100%'>
  <tr><td rowspan=3>ABC</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan=3>123</td><td>22</td><td>33</td></tr>
  <tr><td>44</td><td>55</td></tr>
  <tr><td>66</td><td>77</td></tr>
</table>
```

#### this as group 1

```
<tr><td rowspan=3>ABC</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr>
<tr><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
<tr><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr>
```

#### this as group 2

```
<tr><td rowspan=3>123</td><td>22</td><td>33</td></tr>
<tr><td>44</td><td>55</td></tr>
<tr><td>66</td><td>77</td></tr>
```

## my way

```
var arr_tr=new Array();
$('table tr').each(function(i){
  if(o.find('td:eq(0)').is('[rowspan]')){
    arr_tr[i]=new Array();
      arr_tr[i].push($(this));
    }else{
      arr_tr[i].push(aaa);
  };
});
```

Comment: What is the `o` in `o.find`? You never define it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nextUntil()` and `addBack()` to create each collection

```js
const groups = []

$('tr').has('td[rowspan]').each(function(i) {
  const group = $(this).nextUntil('tr:has(td[rowspan])').addBack();
  groups.push(group);
});

// demonstrate groups by adding class
groups.forEach((jQ, i) => jQ.addClass('group_' + i))

console.log(groups.length)
```

```css
.group_0 {color: red}
.group_1 {color: blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 width='100%'>
  <tr><td rowspan=3>ABC</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan=3>123</td><td>22</td><td>33</td></tr>
  <tr><td>44</td><td>55</td></tr>
  <tr><td>66</td><td>77</td></tr>
</table>
```